# Preserve macro from .accdb to .mdb in MS Access

Tags: database, ms-access

Is there a way to preserve macros when converting from .accdb to .mdb.

I create a beforeChange macro event to set DateModified field whenever any of the row values are modified.
I tested it and it works, however when I save and convert the .accdb to .mdb file, the macro no longer works.

I've added the folder containing the database files  to the MS Access Trust Center locations so there are no macro security warnings.

I need the database file in .mdb format, I convert it to a .accdb file in order to add the macros, then convert it back to a .mdb file. MS Access won't let me create macros for a .mdb file for some reason.

Any ideas ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

**Data macros** were introduced in Access 2010, they only work in the .accdb format.

Even if they would survive the conversion to .mdb, the conversion would be useless, because no Access version that doesn't support .accdb supports them.